# Trying to set array elements constraints

Tags: java, arrays

1.Output: print remainder when sum is divided by max element.
2.Constraints: 1<=n<=100;
           0<=A[i]<=1000

I need this code to validate array elements as such:
pseudocode:
if (arr_elmt>=0 and arr_elmt<=1000) ->Then execute succeeding commands.
 else ->stop program, even though other elements obey constraint

3.

```java
import java.util.Scanner;
public class MyClass {

    public static void main(String args[]) {

    Scanner val = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter no of values:");

    int n;    
    int A[]  = new int[n=val.nextInt()];
    //First constraint  
    if(n>=1 && n<=100)     
    {
       int i=0; 
       for(i=0;i<A.length;i++)
      {
          A[i]=val.nextInt();
      }

     for(i=0;i<A.length;i++) 
      {  //Second constraint      
        if(A[i]>=0 && A[i]<=1000)
       {               

         int sum=0; 
         //Using for-each loop to print array values and get total sum
         for(int t:A) 
         {      
            System.out.print(t+" ");
            sum+=t;
         }  
        //To get largest value
        int largest=A[0];
        for(i=0;i<A.length;i++)//i=1 can work 
        { 
            if(A[i]>largest)
            {
               largest=A[i];    
            }
        }
        //To get and print remainder
        int rem;
        rem=sum%largest;
        System.out.print("\n"+ rem);

       }   
      }
                             }
   }
}
```

4. e.g: input: 3;
    Values: 2988 67 5.

I expect an error due to 2988>1000, but the code
still runs and gives me output!    output obtained:(2988+67+5)mod(2988)

Comment: for(int t:A) this code will run twice for elements 67 and 5. hence will print (2988+67+5)mod(2988) twice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi so your problem is that you do not specified that program should stop (or do whatever you want) when find number which does not match your second constraint.

So right now when does not match second constraint for 2688 it keeps iterating to second item and keep executing rest of your code.

So to make your program end when second constraint is not match you should add something like this

```java
import java.util.Scanner;
public class test {

    public static void main(String args[]) {

    Scanner val = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter no of values:");

    int n;
    int A[] = new int[n=val.nextInt()];
    //First constraint  
    if(n>=1 && n<=100)     
    {

       for(int i=0;i<A.length;i++)
      {
          A[i]=val.nextInt();
      }

     for(int i=0;i<A.length;i++) 
      {  //Second constraint loop through all elements of A[]   
         // if one of it does not obey constraint exit the program

        if(A[i]<=0 || A[i]>=1000) // notice here I change '>' 
       {
        System.exit(0);       // this else is attached to your second constraint
       }
      }

      for(int i = 0; i < A.length; i++){
         int sum=0; 
         //Using for-each loop to print array values and get total sum
         for(int t:A) 
         {      
            System.out.print(t+" ");
            sum+=t;
         }  
        //To get largest value
        int largest=A[0];
        for(int j=0;j<A.length;j++)//i=1 can work 
        { 
            if(A[j]>largest)
            {
               largest=A[j];    
            }
        }
        //To get and print remainder
        int rem;
        rem=sum%largest;
        System.out.println(rem);

      }
    }
   }
}
```

Comment: The code works better now..but when a value is used in other positions apart from first, second constraint doesn't function.  e.g: 67 2988 5 as 3 inputs.. now, constraints won't work!!

Comment: I am glad I could help

Comment: Please guys, help me on this!! I'm a beginner programmer, and I really need to get this code working!!

Comment: What do you mean it does not work? It work for first param `67` and then exit on `2988` is not what you want? You need to be more specific what you want to achieve.

Comment: Please check edited version of code which I upload.